# Extracting group by name in Java regex when the input string can change order

Tags: java, regex

I have a String variation like this:

JEFF 303 JUNE 1989
or the string can be
JEFF 303 1989 JUNE

I am using a reg to match this and want to use group names so that I always knows the data I am extracting. I have a reg ex which can make sure that 1989 and JUNE can be be in 3 and 4th group if string is JEFF 303 1989 JUNE but if the string is JEFF 303 JUNE 1989 it puts June in Group 3 and 1989 in Group 4. I want to avoid that and make sure that either it is extracted by the name of the group or the group number.

I have written the code so far.

```
    final String regex ="^(?<name>[a-z]+)[ :-]?(?<id>\\d+)\\s((?<month>[a-z]+)|(?<year>\\d+))?((?<=[a-z] {0,1})\\d+|(?<=\\d {0,1})(?<month>[a-z]+))$";


        final String string = "JEFF 303 JUNE 1989";

        final String string1 = "JEFF 303 1989 JUNE";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);


        matcher.find();
        String nameGroup = matcher.group("name");
        String id = matcher.group("id");
        String month = matcher.group("month");
        String year = matcher.group("year");
```

Comment: You have to get rid of those assertions. But, what are the exact variations ? I'll give you a regex.

Comment: Give this a try `"^(?i)(?<name>[a-z]+)[ :-]?(?<id>\\d+)\\s+(?:(?<month>[a-z]+)\\s+(?<year>\\d+)|(?<year>\\d+)\\s+(?<month>[a-z]+))$"` on both of those strings, then reference the data with the named groups (not numbered).

Comment: Using the regex from my comment, you could also reference the group number to disambiguate. If group 3 is not empty, then month/year (3/4). else year/month (5/6). Gotta go, good luck!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Named capturing group <year> is already defined near index 81

Comment: Yeah, if you take out the _names_ you can do what I said `Using the regex from my comment, you could also reference the group number to disambiguate. If group 3 is not empty, then month/year (3/4). else year/month (5/6).` viola, no duplicate names, single regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you use named capture groups I don't think you can have the same group name on each side of an alternation `|`. Could you use 2 regexes?

```
public static boolean findMatch(String regex, String input) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

  if(matcher.find()) {
    String name = matcher.group("name");
    String id = matcher.group("id");
    String month = matcher.group("month");
    String year = matcher.group("year");

    // just print it out, maybe you want to return it instead
    System.out.printf("name: %s, id: %s, month: %s, year: %s", name, id, month, year);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String input = "JEFF 303 JUNE 1989";
  //String input = "JEFF 303 1989 JUNE";

  // I simplified the regexes
  String regex1 = "(?<name>\w+) (?<id>\d+) (?<month>\w+) (?<year>\d+)";
  String regex2 = "(?<name>\w+) (?<id>\d+) (?<year>\d+) (?<month>\w+)";

  if(findMatch(regex1, input)) {
    // found it with first regex
  } else if(findMatch(regex2, input)) {
    // found it with second regex
  } else {
    // didn't match
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could but then that would have some performance issue. running two Regex. I was hoping to do it with a single one.

Comment: No problem, I'm not sure how to accomplish what you want with named capture groups. Good luck!